# python regex, match in multiline, but still want to get the line number

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have lots of log files, and want to search some patterns using multiline, but in order to locate matched string easily, I still want to see the line number for matched area.

Any good suggestion. (code sample is copied)

```
string="""
####1
ttteest
####1
ttttteeeestt

####2

ttest
####2
"""

import re
pattern = '.*?####(.*?)####'
matches= re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL).findall(string)
for item in matches:
    print "lineno: ?", "matched: ", item
```

**[UPDATE] the lineno is the actual line number**

So the output I want looks like:

```
    lineno: 1, 1
    ttteest
    lineno: 6, 2
    ttttteeeestt
```

Comment: Are you looking for actual line numbers, or for the numbers you wrote after the `####`?

Comment: thank, I need the actual line numbers, the sample is misleading, I updated it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store the line numbers before hand only and afterwards look for it.

```
import re

string="""
####1
ttteest
####1
ttttteeeestt

####2

ttest
####2
"""

end='.*\n'
line=[]
for m in re.finditer(end, string):
    line.append(m.end())

pattern = '.*?####(.*?)####'
match=re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
for m in re.finditer(match, string):
    print 'lineno :%d, %s' %(next(i for i in range(len(line)) if line[i]>m.start(1)), m.group(1))
```

Comment: close to work, can you check my updated question and sample result

Comment: it shall be group 1, then code `print 'line no %d : %s' %(next(i for i in range(len(line)) if line[i]>m.start(1)), m.group(1))`, please update the code

Comment: Terrible answer. Please don't do this.

Answer (score 11):

This can be done fairly efficiently by:

- Finding all matches
- Looping over newlines, storing the `{offset: line_number}` mapping up until the last match.
- For each match, reverse find the offset of the first newline beforehand and looking up it's line number in the map.

This avoids counting back to the beginning of the file for every match.

The following function is similar to `re.finditer`

```
def finditer_with_line_numbers(pattern, string, flags=0):
    '''
    A version of 're.finditer' that returns '(match, line_number)' pairs.
    '''
    import re

    matches = list(re.finditer(pattern, string, flags))
    if not matches:
        return []

    end = matches[-1].start()
    # -1 so a failed 'rfind' maps to the first line.
    newline_table = {-1: 0}
    for i, m in enumerate(re.finditer('\\n', string), 1):
        # Don't find newlines past our last match.
        offset = m.start()
        if offset > end:
            break
        newline_table[offset] = i

    # Failing to find the newline is OK, -1 maps to 0.
    for m in matches:
        newline_offset = string.rfind('\n', 0, m.start())
        line_number = newline_table[newline_offset]
        yield (m, line_number)
```

If you want the contents, you can replace the last loop with:

```
    for m in matches:
        newline_offset = string.rfind('\n', 0, m.start())
        newline_end = string.find('\n', m.end())  # '-1' gracefully uses the end.
        line = string[newline_offset + 1:newline_end]
        line_number = newline_table[newline_offset]
        yield (m, line_number, line)
```

Note that it would be nice to avoid having to create a list from `finditer`, however that means we won't know when to stop storing newlines *(where it could end up storing many newlines even if the only pattern match is at the beginning of the file)*.

If it was important to avoid storing all matches - it's possible to make an iterator that scans newlines as-needed, though not sure this would give you much advantage in practice.

Comment: In `re.finditer(r'\n', string)`, is it correct that this is a raw string?

Comment: It works but it's not needed, use double back-slash.

Answer (score 8):

What you want is a typical task that regex is not very good at; parsing.

You could read the logfile line by line, and search that line for the strings you are using to delimit your search. You could use regex line by line, but it is less efficient than regular string matching unless you are looking for complicated patterns.

And if you **are** looking for complicated matches, I'd like to see it. Searching every line in a file for `####` while maintaining the line count is easier without regex.

Comment: this is quite reasonable, and I want to see whether there is possible elegant solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

The finditer function can tell you the character range that matched. From this you can use a simple newline regular expression to count how many newlines were before the match. Add one to the number of newlines to get the line number, as our convention in manipulating text in an editor is to call the first line 1 rather than 0.

```
def multiline_re_with_linenumber():
    string="""
####1
ttteest
####1
ttttteeeestt

####2

ttest
####2
"""
    re_pattern = re.compile(r'.*?####(.*?)####', re.DOTALL)
    re_newline = re.compile(r'\n')
    count = 0
    for m in re_pattern.finditer(string):
        count += 1
        start_line = len(re_newline.findall(string, 0, m.start(1)))+1
        end_line = len(re_newline.findall(string, 0, m.end(1)))+1
        print ('"""{}"""\nstart={}, end={}, instance={}'.format(m.group(1), start_line, end_line, count))
```

Gives this output

```
"""1
ttteest
"""
start=2, end=4, instance=1
"""2

ttest
"""
start=7, end=10, instance=2
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does more or less what you want:

```
import re

string="""
####1
ttteest
####1
ttttteeeestt

####2

ttest
####2
"""

pattern = '.*?####(.*?)####'
matches = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
for match in matches.finditer(string):
    start, end = string[0:match.start()].count("\n"), string[0:match.end()].count("\n")
    print("lineno: %d-%d matched: %s" % (start, end, match.group()))
```

It might be a *little* slower than other options because it repeatedly does a substring match and search on the string, but since the string is small in your example, i think it's worth the tradeoff for simplicity.

What we gain here is also the *range* of lines that match the pattern, which allows us to extract the whole string in one swoop as well. We might optimize this further by counting the number of newlines in the match instead of going straight for the end, for what it's worth.

Answer (score -2):

```
import re

text = """
####1
ttteest
####1
ttttteeeestt

####2   

ttest
####2
"""

pat = ('^####(\d+)'
       '(?:[^\S\n]*\n)*'
       '\s*(.+?)\s*\n'
       '^####\\1(?=\D)')
regx = re.compile(pat,re.MULTILINE)

print '\n'.join("lineno: %s  matched: %s" % t
                for t in regx.findall(text))
```

result

```
lineno: 1  matched: ttteest
lineno: 2  matched: ttest
```